# How do i output contents of a map using operator <<

Tags: c++

I'm trying to output the contents of my map but i'm not sure on how to go about it. i've got the following declarations for a map and a iterator set as private in my header file

```
typedef map<long, string> Student;
Student newstudent;
typedef Student::const_iterator studentItr;
studentItr itr;
```

and i have the following declaration in my .cpp

```
map<long, string> classname::GetMap()
{
    for(itr = newstudent.begin(); itr !=newstudent.end(); itr++)
{
    cout << itr->first << " => " <<itr->second << '\n';
}

    return newstudent;
}
```

and this is how i'm trying to pass this into my overloaded operator << function

```
ostream & operator <<( ostream & os, classname & R)
{
    os << " " << R.GetMap() << '\n';

    return os;
}
```

Usually this would work for any other function but since its a map i get the following error:

> no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream< char >' and 'std::map < long int, std::__cxx11::basic_string< char > > ')|

Could anybody point me in the right direction of what i'm doing wrong

EDIT: Thanks for posting your suggestions i appreciate the help, but i think something isnt right either with my complier or with how i've stated something.

Everytime i try using `Student` as a type it wont register as a type and i get an error about it.

E.g if i declare this statement

```
ostream & operator <<( ostream & os, const Student & R)
```

OR

```
Student & classname::GetMap()
```

i get the error:

> 'Student' does not name a type

This error ultimately is leading to nothing within my statements making any sense and i'm not sure how to fix that

Comment: A `std::map` does not have an `operator<<()`.    Instead of trying to simply send the map to the output stream,  create a loop that iterates over elements of the map and outputs them.

Comment: Does your compiler support `using`, such as `using u8 = std::uint8_t;`?

Comment: @FrancisCugler i'm not entirely sure how to check that, i've typed into my codeblocks that statement, 'using' pops up but the second statement 'using u8 = std::uint8_t;' doesent register as anything.

Comment: You would have to have the proper include for `std::uint8_t` then you would use it to declare a type. So to use it would be like this: `u8 valueA = 9;` It's very similar to how `typedef` works, but it's a little more elegant and expressive I think. I believe the best include for `std::uint8_t` is `<cstdint>`

Comment: You can take a look at my answer to see how I'm using the `using` directive instead of using `typedefs`.

Answer (score 3):

So you seem to have put the output code inside for `GetMap` function for some reason. Either you want a routine called `GetMap` which just gets a map, or you want a routine called `PrintMap` (for instance) which outputs the map. You have half and half. Here's one way to do it

```
void classname::PrintMap() const
{
    for(itr = newstudent.begin(); itr !=newstudent.end(); itr++)
    {
        cout << itr->first << " => " <<itr->second << '\n';
    }
}

ostream & operator <<( ostream & os, classname & R)
{
    os << " ";
    R.printMap();
    os << '\n';
    return os;
}
```

This could be improved, for instance you could pass the stream you want to output to, to the `PrintMap` function. Like this

```
void classname::PrintMap(ostream & os) const
{
    for(itr = newstudent.begin(); itr !=newstudent.end(); itr++)
    {
        os << itr->first << " => " <<itr->second << '\n';
    }
}

ostream & operator <<( ostream & os, classname & R)
{
    os << " ";
    R.printMap(os);
    os << '\n';
    return os;
}
```

FInally you could follow the common convention and rename `PrintMap` as `operator<<` and make it a friend function instead of a member function.

```
Student& classname::GetMap()
{
    return newstudent;
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const Student& s)
{
    for(itr = s.begin(); itr !=s.end(); itr++)
    {
        os << itr->first << " => " <<itr->second << '\n';
    }
    return os;
}

ostream & operator <<( ostream & os, classname & R)
{
    os << " " << R.getMap() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing this aproach but i get the same error except with 'void': no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'void')|

Comment: @Stan That's probably because you are doing something like `os << R.printMap();` instead of `R.printMap();`. `printMap` returns `void`.

Comment: @Stan Seems to be some confusion about how C++ works. `operator<<` is just a convention. It not a magic device for doing output, it's just an operator that follows the same rules as the rest of C++, and you cannot pass a `void` value to an operator.

Comment: i've tried both approaches for getmap but i get an error eitherway, this time being "class classname has no member name getmap eventhough when i use the dot operator it comes up as an option, but  whenever i try using Student as the type i get an error 'Student does not name a type' which brings up a whole lot more errors.

Comment: @Stan Well then your errors go further than the code you have posted here. Since it seems you have multiple errors in your code, the best advice is to start again and build up your code slowly, add a few lines of code at a time. Get that working (compiling and running) before you go any further. That way you are only solving one problem at a time. Programming is much easier that way.

Comment: Very thorough answer which covers all the bits that need pointing out / teaching here. 

Comment: Also _commit your code to version control_ before moving on to the next problem. That way, even if you undo your previous success, you can just roll back and try again.

Answer (score 3):

You could make an operator << for your map type. (totally untested code)

```
ostream & operator <<( ostream & os, const Student & R) {
    for(studentIter itr = R.begin(); itr !=R.end(); itr++){
        os << itr->first << " => " <<itr->second << '\n';
    }
    return os;
}
```

Edit:
Changed the names to match those in your question.

Comment: @Surt i have tried something similar to this beforehand but i get errors for itr not being declared in the scope. also i'm not supose to be using auto in this code, this is for an assignment. plus my complier doesent like it.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: You can also try replacing the loop with `for(const std::pair<long, std::string>& p : R) os << p.first << " => " << p.second << '\n';`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm using the GNU GCC Compiler, my c++ compiler is mingw32-g++.exe, i hope that answers that question.

Comment: @Stan Yeah,. What is the error you get if you try the code in this answer?

Comment: What _version_ of the compiler? Always important also. There have been hundreds of incarnations of MinGW GCC.

Answer (score 2):

Initially you are trying to insert an `std::map` directly into the `operator<<()`. This will not work because `std::map` has no idea how to convert to a `std::ostream` object and `std::ostream`'s `operator<<()` doesn't know how to accept a map.

You can always write an overload of `operator<<()` for your map type, however if a type inside of your map is a non trivial type such as a class or struct with multiple fields then that class would have to have its own associated `operator<<()` as well. So it's just easier to write them for the types themselves and just iterate over the map or collection.

So now that the class has a working relation with `operator<<()` you can iterate over any kind of container either it be a vector, an array, a list or queue etc. The `operator<<()` doesn't care about what kind of container, it only cares about the object that is in the container.

Do not try to get into the habit of declaring an `operator<<()` or `operator>>()` as a member of a class, try to get into the habit of writing the operators as just that a standalone operator function that works on your type!

---

Here is a complete demonstration:

---

If your compiler supports `using` in place of `typedefs`; You can try this program and check its expected output. There shouldn't be any errors, but there might be a typo that I've overlooked when I was fixing the formatting. If you find one let me know and I'll update it accordingly.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Students.h"

int main() {
    using namespace "your namespace here";

    Student JacobKnight("Jacob Knight", 233);
    Student SaraAndrews("Sara Andrews", 245);
    Student AllenReed("Allen Reed", 259);

    Students students;
    addStudent(JacobKnight, students);
    addStudent(SarahAndrews, students);
    addStudent(AllenReed, students);

    using It = std::map<long, Student>::const_iterator;
    for (It it = students.cbegin(); it != students.cend(); ++it) {
        std::cout << "Map ID: " << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) 
        << it->first << "\nStudent: " << it->second;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Students.h**

```
#pragma once   // if your compiler doesn't like this then use header guards!

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

namespace "your namespace here" {

    struct Student {
        long id_;
        std::string name_;

        Student() = default;
        Student(const std::string name, long id) : name_{name}, id_{id} {}
    };

    using Students = std::map<long, Student>;

    void addStudent(const Student& student, Students& students) {
        students.insert( std::make_pair( student.id_, student ) );
    }

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Student& student) {
        return os << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << student.id_
                  << " " << student.name_ << "\n\n";
    }

} // your namespace
```

**Output**

```
Map  ID: 00000233
Student: 00000233 Jacob Knight

Map  ID: 00000245
Student: 00000245 Sarah Andrews

Map  ID: 00000259
Student: 00000259 Allen Reed
```

---

Here I like to think of a single student as a single object and that it contains the details of that object, a numerical id, and a character array or string name. So I put these in a struct as public members. You can always change this to a class, make them private with accessory functions to encapsulate the data, but for quick demonstration, I made a simple structure or class here nothing too complex.

Next I used the using directive to define a typename of a type. Now I can later on easily use this to declare my objects. I used this to simplify the usage of `std::map<T1,T2>`. I also use the using directive again in main to define my iterator typename as It. Then I use that to declare my iterator for my map.

I wrote a simple function that will populate a map of students. To me this is more intuitive and expressive because a map contains multiple objects and in this case students, hence being plural where the structure itself of a single entity is just a student! This makes the code expressive and readable and helps to imply your intent.

Then I simply wrote an overloaded `operator<<()` that takes in a `Student` by `const ref`. It then formats the output to either my liking or the required layout. Then it returns it back to the stream operator for insertion into the stream output to the standard out either it being the console or to a file.

I hope this answer(s) your question(s) and that it will give you some guidance along the way...

---

*EDIT*

In main.cpp I changed the map's iterators from `begin()` and `end()` in the for loop to `cbegin()` and `cend()`. This shouldn't make a big difference but since my map's iterator was declared as a `const_iterator`. I prefer staying consistent with the type of iterators that I'm traversing over.